# Domain Driven Design using Environment Variables for .NET Microservices

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to work with Domain Driven Design, in a .NET 6 project, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the following.

In my previous Big Ball of Mud projects we've typically stored Application configuration variables in environment variables (and/or appsettings.json).
My understanding of DDD is we are shifting the business rules/logic into the Domain Layer to organize it separate to our Application Layer (implementation detail).

I've done training on Pluralsight and also reviewed Microsoft's DDD-orientated microservice (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/ddd-oriented-microservice) and Clean Architecture. Its clear that the Domain Layer should be referencing anything in the Application Layer.
To me, using `appsettings.json` seems to be part of the Application Layer's implementation detail - so my question is, "is it not possible to use appsettings.json with the Domain Layer?"?

I raise this question because I want to allow for certain variables to be defined with appsettings.json, however I also want to be able to use those variables to enforce Guards within my Domain Layer.

For example, I want to define a "user's default session length" in the environment variables, but I also want to enforce that session length in the Domain Layer when creating or updating entities.
I know I can do this in the Application Layer, but it feels wrong to move something that should be tied to Domain Entity into the Application Layer.

Any help or opinions would be appreciated.

Comment: Domain layer => strong type to represent what can be configured. Application layer => appsettings.json & environment variables & DI & ... to supply configuration values.

Answer (score 1):

Broad strokes: the code that figures out what to do with information lives inside the domain layer.  The code that figures out where the information comes from lives outside the domain layer.

So you'll have code outside the domain layer that reads your environment variables, or reads appsettings.json, or whatever, and the values are passed to the domain layer as arguments.

I can think of at least three variations

- The domain layer defines an *interface* for accessing this implementation; the application layer implements that interface, and passes a reference to its implementation to the domain layer
- The domain layer defines a data structure for representing this information, and offers affordances for creating instances of these data structures (ex: a factory method)
- The domain layer defines an interface that accepts this information in some general purpose representation (ex: Strings, ints, arrays of bytes, etc) and hides the details of how that information might be organized into data structures.

Answer (score 0):

I always like to ask myself the following questions:

> If the users tell you their stories what they want to do with the software, do they really care about that thing? In your example, *user's default session length*? Is that something **they** brought up, or is it a technical aspect which arose from **your** mind?

- If they **don't** care, then it's technical and only part of the Application layer, not the Domain
- If they **do** care, then it should be part of the domain. The next question to the users then is: "*Do you need to configure it by yourself?*"

  - If they say **yes**, then the session length would be part of an Aggregate and would not be injected via settings, but set by an user interaction with the app
  - If they say **no**, they most likely have a specific default length in mind. Then I would explicitly model this value "hard-wired" in the Domain and don't make it configurable, because it's a definite business rule and must expressed accordingly in the Domain code (maybe a constant in the Aggregate, which needs it).

You can generalize this thinking to every feature you implement. So naturally there should never be a need to configure domain business rules via `appsettings.json`. Or conversely: Having the need to configure the domain via settings could be a misunderstanding of DDD.

Or you can think about it this way: An Aggregate ensures the transactional consistency of business rules. If you could change values via `appsettings.json`, what does that mean for the business rules? Without any user interaction, the consistency is defined differently today for all Aggregate instances than yesterday? What does that mean for existing instances, are they now just invalid? Doesn't sound like DDD in my ears.